# AS3 and link image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security

I have a little problem in my `Flash` animation. I have a quiz with different images.
Some images load fine, but others do not. I have the following **`error message`** :-

```
SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation... 
No policy files granted access.
```

But, I have:

```
function onLoadQuiz(dataQuiz){
    onLoadSecurity.loadPolicyFile("https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/crossdomain.xml");
    var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(); 
    context.checkPolicyFile = true;

    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest(dataQuiz.srcImage);
    var img:Loader = new Loader();

    img.load(url, context);
    img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImageLoaded);
    myLoader.load(url);
}
```

and

```
function onImageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var image:Bitmap = e.target.content;
    image.width = 150;
    image.height = 150;
    image.x = 400;
    image.y = 150;
    addChild(image);
}
```

I don't understand why some images load fine, and others (majority) doesn't.

Comment: Error message specifically mentions policy files and your code references a custom policy file, might be worth including it.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633942/alternative-to-bitmapdata-draw-for-error ?

Comment: Like this @CyanAngel?https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2428056/policy.xml

@burmaDLX in that solution, if image doesn't load, doesn't show anything, and I have to show the image

Comment: Could you give us some example of urls used in your code, working and not working ones ?

Comment: is the issue here that you don't understand the error? or that you think that error should not have occurred?

Comment: This error should not have occurred...but I changed the images and solved my problem solved.I don't why, but some image resources doesn't work.